# DebugDiag 1.2 minidumps are corrupt?

Tags: debugging, windbg, minidump, debugdiag

I have two 32-bit Windows Server 2003 R2, SP2 machines. I've tried using DebugDiag 1.2 to perform a performance-based dump of an IIS App Pool. I've tried this on both servers and they are coming up with a .dmp file that cannot be read by WinDBG/Visual Studio/DebugDiag.

I have been able to successfully create a manual .dmp file in the past using Adplus.vbs from the command line.

When using dumpchk.exe I get this message:

```
C:\debugging\server>"c:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\dumpchk.exe" w3wp.exe_HTTPRESPONSE_RULE1.dmp
Loading dump file w3wp.exe_HTTPRESPONSE_RULE1.dmp

Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.12.0002.633 X86
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\debugging\server\w3wp.exe_HTTPRESPONSE_RULE1.dmp]
Minidump does not have system info
Could not open dump file [w3wp.exe_HTTPRESPONSE_RULE1.dmp], HRESULT 0x80004005
    "Unspecified error"
**** DebugClient cannot open DumpFile - error 80004005
```

Has anyone else run across something like this?

Comment: What is the size of the dump file? Have you tried any newer versions of WinDbg like 6.2?

Comment: Maybe you can also try SysInternals ProcDump as a replacement of DebugDiag. It also works on Server 2003 or higher and also provides options for creating dumps on performance counters. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx

Comment: Strange, I have used DebugDiag 1.2 and dump / leak analysis on W 7 and w 8. these dumps are also possible to open in windbg, but I use the latest from sdk 8.1

Comment: have only used full dump on both 32 and 64 bits processes but on 64 bits OS.

Comment: @KjellGunnar, I too have used it successfully in the past, on these servers, but for some reason yesterday it did not work correctly.  :|  I thought it odd that I got the same result from two different servers.

Comment: @ThomasW., the small dumps were about 1,500KB and those opened correctly inside of WinDbg, but I couldn't get SOS to load for whatever reason. The full dumps were 300-400MB, which matched the size of what the app pools were using at the time. I am thinking I will try your suggestion of ProcDump and see if that results in a more useful output.

Comment: Anyone actually _got_ a better result with procdump, or has this been a one-time issue for everyone?